# How to set breakpoint to JavaScript's files

Tags: javascript, developer-tools

I'm trying to understand how it works a webpage that has some JavaScript codes but I'm no able to see what happens even I'm adding breakpoints in Dev Tools.

In html part I see the script is declared like `type="text/htmlpreview"`and not like `type="text/javascript"`

```
    <!-- javascript
         (Placed at the bottom so the DOM loads faster) -->
    <script type="text/htmlpreview" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/htmlpreview" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/htmlpreview" src="../sjme.js"></script>
    <script type="text/htmlpreview" src="assets/js/mmp.js"></script>
```

And in Sources (within Dev Tools), I see a folder named `htmlpreview.js` but doesn't contain any of the scripts declared above(for example sjme.js or mmp.js).

How can I set a breakpoint within the declared javascript files inside the sentences `<script>..</script>`? in order to be able to see which functions are triggered each time.

**UPDATE**

This is the [site](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/robatron/sudoku.js/blob/master/demo/index.html) for which I'm trying to see which functions are triggered when is clicked on labels "Easy", "Medium", "hard", etc or when are clicked the buttons "solve", "candidates"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unfortunately, unless you direct us to the website in question, we can only guess.

Comment: @DanielB I've added and update to my original post with the URL of the site I'm trying to debug in order to see which functions are involved when each button is clicked.

Comment: You'd have much bigger luck asking on SO, this is mainly a JS/HTML related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you’re looking at is a “proxy” of sorts, only implemented purely in JavaScript. You’re visiting `https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/robatron/sudoku.js/blob/master/demo/index.html`. The page that is shown is from the `robatron/sudoku.js` repository, yet the proxy application is served from `https://htmlpreview.github.io`. If you try to load, say, `assets/js/jquery.min.js` from this site, it will fail.

The proxy application transforms the HTML like this to stop the browser from actually processing the script. Instead, it will load the script itself from the correct URL and add it inline in a `<script>` tag. That’s also why you won’t see separate files for the scripts, it’s all (effectively) inline. Unfortunately, at least in Firefox, inline scripts do not show up in the Debugger section of Developer Tools. In Chrome, they do, [given proper annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39156149/1025421). Which the proxy script does not generate.

Your best bet is to simply *not* use `https://htmlpreview.github.io/`. Instead, you should download what it points to (`https://github.com/robatron/sudoku.js/blob/master/demo/index.html`) or perhaps the entire repository it points to.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your answer. I've tried to download it with httrack but begins to download the whole `https://github.com/` site, not only what I interested for. I think would need to do it manually.

Comment: You can easily download a snapshot of [the repository](https://github.com/robatron/sudoku.js) right from the GitHub web. There is no need to use any additional tools. Click the _Code_ button, select _Download ZIP_, done. Alternatively, you can use [Git](https://git-scm.com/) (or any Git GUI) to download and upload code from and to GitHub.

Comment: Nice, I was doing the wrong thing. Now, I downloaded the Zip as you said. Now to try it locally I think I'll need to replace within the code each occurrence of  `https://github.com/robatron/` for `C:/testsite/sudoku.js/`? is correct?

Comment: No. The page at `demo/index.html` will just work, all required resources are referred to using relative URLs.

Comment: Thanks so much Daniel for answer and for your time. I'll try as you said. Regards